# React Material UI Button component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks, dependencies

I have installed create-react-app and material-ui/core and have proceeded to make a simple Button.

After adding the Button to App file and using command npm start I'd expect the button to show in the browser, instead I get Error invalid hook call.

The only issue I could think of is the dependencies may be corrupt as the hook is clearly valid.

Here is the simple Button:
App.js

```
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Button>Click Me</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Index.html

```
<div id='root'></div>
```

And here is the package.json file (dependencies only shown here to reduce code length):

```
{
  "name": "mui-play",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: There was an issue with the dependencies, I learned that even if you install an npm package you should still go to the terminal in the source code editor and install the dependency into the package.json file if it does not do it automatically. Here is the fixed file that allows the button to be displayed in the browser:
package.json:

```
  "name": "mui-play",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

The line `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",` has been added so that the package can use the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

try by adding the packages you want manually and then run `npm install` on the terminal
[image]